# What is the replication method used for the GCP CloudSQL Read Replica for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, read-replication

Based on the descriptions it seems that for the Read Replicas for Postgresql, the [Write-Ahead Log Shipping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html) is used.
Is it logical? I have tables without primary keys, however when I spin up a read replica I have no problems so wonder what is being used behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud SQL "native" Postgres replicas (e.g., those you create via [Cloud Console/gcloud/API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/create-replica)) uses Postgres' built-in streaming physical replication which involves WAL segment shipping from primary to replica(s).

The needing primary keys is a constraint that exists in logical replication using an extension like `pg_logical`. You can configure your own replication relationships using [`pg_logical`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication) (as well as postgres' own built in logical decoding on versions that support it) in Cloud SQL but this isn't the same as native replication offering which is fully managed by Google.

But to answer your question directly: Cloud SQL's native read replicas, like the one you referred, uses WAL shipping (physical/streaming replication) as you suspect. Which is why your tables replicate just fine without primary keys.

Comment: This is the official answer I was searching for. Would be great if it is added on the docs. Kind regards!

Comment: @roopa-m is there any way to set up physical replication from CloudSQL to a self-hosted instance on GCE?

Comment: @HarshitJoshi: Nope. [CloudSQL doc on replication use cases](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication#replication_use_cases) : Any other replica type than Cloud SQL instance requires logical replication. See also the [excellent answer on diffs between logical and physical replication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622916/11394520): As physical replication happens on very low (disk block) level,  master and replica must be "very similar"

Comment: @HarshitJoshi: You might find [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-external-replica) a very good starting point

Comment: @ThomasW. Thanks for the link. I think it still links to logical replication while my question was about physical replication. I believe it just isn't possible and I confirmed it with GCP support as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

will show you the type of replication.